# How to get parent URL in JS without using document.referrer

Tags: javascript, redirect, parent, referrer-policy

I need to get the parent url which redirect to current page using JS, I find document.referrer can achieve, but our company has some security rules said *can't trust that the referrer header is safe - it can be spoofed, omitted, or have an unexpected format.*

I am asking are there any other way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The other way I know of is looking into the window object

```
window.location.origin
```